# PHP-Mysql database Windows Installer

Tags: php, mysql, windows-installer

I have designed a simple database on my local computer at work. But I need to install it on some other computers at work. It is a personal database for private use for my colleagues. I wonder if there is any way to make is as a package to install the components (PHP5, Mysql database and Apache webserver) altogether through a .exe or any windows installable file.

Comment: i think that you need a backup of your database. am i right??

Comment: Sounds like you're trying to drop a WAMP install on the user's machine.

Comment: No I do not want to back up or even install WAMP on computers. I just want to see if I can make it installable like any windows application, like ms office, quick book and etc...

Answer (score 0):

WAMP or XAMPP are executables which install Apache, PHP and MYSQL servers, so just export your database into sql file, install WAMP or XAMPP and import the file into phpMyAdmin on every machine.

I don't know if this is the best solution for you, I think that the best solution is that all users to see the same database, so you'll have to read more about making a shared server.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you want to install the whole setup on each machine ? Because generally database and server side application code resides on one central server and other client make access to it.

Anyways, if you want to setup on each machine, then there are two approaches:

1. All these components are available as zip file install - means you can just extract and run from that folder directly without any installation. You can setup your environment and data in that manner including applications (PHP, Database and Web server), change their configuration files accordingly so that they point to correct locations / paths and create data files (for database, web app etc.) in respective folders. Then simply zip everything and share. The target user can simply extract it and have everything running upon extract.
   You may need to change windows settings e.g. firewall etc. on target computer manually.
2. Second approach is you keep installers of each component (apache, php, database) and also have one custom installer which will setup your own customizations e.g. creating a database, configuring php and apache etc. Then create a master installer and run the above installers one by one.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft WPI (Web Platform Installer) is the best choice if you want work with PHP Framwork on IIS.
On WPI there are a lot pool of applications subdivided into categories like Databases, IIS Tools, .NET, Development Tools, CMS etc.
All installation are unattended.

http://www.microsoft.com/web/downloads/platform.aspx